# ACRA and proguard, incorrect line number

Tags: android, proguard, acra

I am using proguard with the ACRA.

The problem is that the line numbers I am getting are incorrect. I get the crash report from ACRA, then I decode it using the Proguard GUI retrace tool. I get the line number, I look in the code and statment is totally not what crash is showing. I know that proguard shrinks and optimize the code, so is there any way I can somehow get around al lthis and get the correct line number?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The mapping file for ReTrace should correspond to the processed code that you released and to the source code that you are looking at now. The line numbers can be off otherwise.

Comment: Yes i am following that. However proguard shrinks and optimize code. The mapping only contains symbol-name mapping but dors indicate shrunk line. Thats why I expect line numbers to be off either way right? Wondering if only me facing it

Comment: Eric elaborates on this a little more in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929116/154306). Simply put, in some cases, the line number simply cannot reliably be displayed due to merging or method inlining.