# Incorrect line number with ACRA

Tags: android, proguard, acra

I  user android/proguard/ACRA. Can anyone tell me please why the crash reports  I am getting have incorrect line numbers (line number pointing at obviously a wrong statment)?

It is really annoying that I am unable to know the exact line number of the crash so I can't fix my user's reported error
Thank you

PS: I am using the mapping file corresponding to version I am releasing

Comment: Are they all wrong, or only a minority?  I'd be tempted to try introducing a known error in a test build and see if I could get back a correct (or incorrect) report from that known condition.

Comment: good Idea  I will try that. the problem is that either the line is incorrect, or the line is a function call (so somehwere in that function there is a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for who is interested. You should avoid (preverify, optimize, and shrink). This will display all lines numbers correctly as the code is not played with

Comment: Optimization can affect line numbers (see my answer). Shrinking and preverification can not affect line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

With some optimizations (notably class merging and method inlining), ProGuard may be unable to preserve all debug information, because the java class file format doesn't support it. The information may only be an approximation in those cases. These should be exceptions though; if the information is consistently wrong, you're probably using the wrong mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of research and trying many approaches. I have found the solution.

Change

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(`**'proguard-android-optimize.txt'**`)...`

to

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(`**'proguard-android.txt'**`)...`